# HTML / CSS - Sticky Footer problems

Tags: html, css

I feel kinda ashamed that I have to post this question here.
My webpage has a footer which I want to stay at the bottom, when I add content I want the footer to just move down.

I've tried several solutions which were available through stackoverflow, to no success unfortunately.

**TL;DR** Sticky Footer that sticks at the bottom

My HTML Structure:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="pageWrap">
       <nav></nav>
       <div id="contentWrap">
           <div id="contentHeader">some text</div>
           <div id="content">
               <!-- Content -->
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Here's the odd thing: When I use the inspect element feature I notice my pagewrap height is `182px`. My divs inside the pagewarp have much larger content than 182px, and I never even set a height.

Basically the elements **inside** the pagewrap fall **outside** of the bounds of that wrap. I feel like this screws up the footer location.

EDIT:

Relevant CSS:

```
html, body {  height: 100%;  }
#contentWrap{ width: 90%;  margin: 0 auto; word-wrap: break-word }
#content{ margin-top: 30px;}
footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border-top: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
}
```

Comment: you should post your css as well.

Comment: what happens when you use position:fixed for the footer element?

Comment: @sweaver2112 I updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try floating `#pagewrap` or add `overflow:hidden`. It makes the element content aware which may cause it to scale. That's all I can think of without seeing something of a demo.

You should also make sure the elements inside the `#pagewrap` are set to `position:relative` if you want them to scale `#pagewrap`.